# How to save image in database and upload from database to server?

Tags: android, image, android-camera, image-uploading

I am capturing the image from camara and showing in image view.I want to save the image into database and want to upload to server . How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create table with the field type Blob in Sqlite3 database

call readable databse

insert record into table

Comment: But in sqlite database we can't take a blob datatype .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what code you have written. Just follow the below post. It will give you a proper solution

[Add Image from Gallery and Camera into SqLite Database](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

ands [example](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/) can help you out.